# printing character from char pointer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char *arr = "This is to test";
 printf("\n%c %c ",*(arr++), *(arr++));
 return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `h T` rather than outputting `h h`. Why is it so?

Comment: Two words: Undefined Behavio(u)r

Comment: There's no way it would output `h h`... it may output `h T` or `T h` (depending on the order of evaluation of the parameters, which is not defined), but `h h` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I expect he thought arr++ was the same as arr+1. He did not realize that ++ actually modifies arr.

Comment: yeah i thought as rudy says. Now i'm clear with the arr++ ans arr+1.

Comment: @Rudy: uh, now it's clear. Many years of C-like languages make you forget that it's not *that* obvious that `x++` means `x=x+1` (returning `x` before the increment). `:)`

Comment: @Matteo, what "doesn't make sense" actually doesn't matter too much for UB, because compiler optimizers are allowed to let it do anything, and often end up causing it to do seemingly illogical things. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html

Comment: @Karl: I know, what I meant was that *expecting* `h h` didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arr++ is equivalent to arr += 1. You are actually incrementing arr. This is what is happening in your situation.

```
printf("\n%c %c ",*(arr++), *(arr++));
//                  ^         ^Evaluates to 0 therefore prints T then increments by 1
//                  ^Evaluates to 1 therefore prints h and then increments by 1
//Now if where to prinf %s arr it should print "is is to test"
```

What you want to do is

```
printf("\n%c %c ",*(arr+1), *(arr+1));
```

**Note:** As others have pointed out multiple pre/postfix ++/-- produce undefined behavior (order of evaluation) and should be avoided, although I understand in your situation you were not trying to modify the original array.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why 'h' is printed before 'T' in his situation. However, it does answer the second part of his question about why it isn't 'h' 'h'.

Comment: I think it does answer the question why `h T` is the output. See the comments.

Answer (score 7):

Using two increment operators in one statement that are independent from each other leads to undefined behaviour because the compiler is free to choose which increment to do first (or rather you didn't give the compiler any hint which one to do first).

Anyway, if you're expecting `h h`, it's also wrong to write `*(arr++)` twice, because they will be executed both, incrementing `arr` *twice* - and so there will be two different characters printed (`arr[0]` and `arr[1]`).

Another error is using post-increment which will lead to `arr` being incremented *after* the character was fetched, so it will output `T`, not `h`.

So a possible solution is this code, using an additional variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char *arr = "This is to test";
 char c = *(++arr);
 printf("\n%c %c ", c, c);
 return 0;
}
```

In this code, `arr` will only be incremented once and the character fetched at this position can be used later.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because both ++'es move the pointer forward one step after printing, and with the code generated by most compilers today the rightmost one will be done first. and then it will move left.

This is because the unary operator arr++ will cause `arr = arr + 1;` and since it is using a postfix operator it will print before assigning the result to arr.

So the steps that are executed are:

1. Print T
2. move pointer to h
3. Print h
4. move pointer to i

If you had three in the same line you would get i h T as that would cause it to move a third time.

What I believe you are trying to do is something to the effect of:

```
printf("\n%c %c ",*(arr+1), *(arr+1));
```

Comment: "and with the code generated by most compilers today" I think that this is not really dependent from the compiler itself, but from the calling convention used on the architecture (in particular, from the order of parameters on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

if u r supposed to get output h h.
then u have to write

```
printf("\n%c  %c",*(arr+1),*(arr+1));
```

but here in your code you updated arr and this increment is post increment so first it assign the value to the function argument then variable will increment.
in function

```
printf("\n%c %c ",*(arr++), *(arr++));
```

values assigned from left to right on stack so u can imagine like following statement:

```
printf("\n%c %c ",'h', 'T');
```

and argument "\n%c %c " will print the output from left to right and u got the output h T.